# Download JSON response from website with array

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, url, python-requests

I'm trying to get a JSON response from a website that has a different ending, for example:

```
http//example.com/111
http//example.com/112
http//example.com/113
...
http//example.com/200
```

Every request gives me JSON with the same columns but different data:

```
{
    "uid": 111,
    "name": "Pinky",
    "title": "Mouse",
    "type": "No brain"
}   

{
    "uid": 112,
    "name": "Brain",
    "title": "Big Mouse",
    "type": "Brain"
}

{
    "uid": 113,
    "name": "Garfield",
    "title": "Cat",
    "type": "lazy"
}
```

I'm having trouble with a Python script that get all the JSON data and unites it into one from the defined array, for example: [111 - 200]

```
[
    {
        "uid": 111,
        "name": "Pinky",
        "title": "Mouse",
        "type": "No brain"
    },
    {
        "uid": 112,
        "name": "Brain",
        "title": "Big Mouse",
        "type": "Brain"
    },
    {
        "uid": 113,
        "name": "Garfield",
        "title": "Cat",
        "type": "lazy"
    }
]
```

Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76682732/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the results in a list and save them to JSON at once.

I am taking PokeAPI as an example here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

pokemons = []
for poke_id in range(1, 7):
    url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{poke_id}'
    
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    data = {
        'id':data.pop('id'),
        'types': data.pop('types'),
        'base_experience': data.pop('base_experience')
    } # to filter a few attributes only

    print(data)
    pokemons.append(data)

with open('pokemon.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(pokemons, f)
```

With each iteration of loop, I am appending a webpage's result to the list, and at last writing to the JSON file.

This is the output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "grass",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
                }
            },
            {
                "slot": 2,
                "type": {
                    "name": "poison",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 64
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "grass",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
                }
            },
            {
                "slot": 2,
                "type": {
                    "name": "poison",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 142
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "grass",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
                }
            },
            {
                "slot": 2,
                "type": {
                    "name": "poison",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 263
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "fire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 62
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "fire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 142
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "name": "fire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10/"
                }
            },
            {
                "slot": 2,
                "type": {
                    "name": "flying",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/"
                }
            }
        ],
        "base_experience": 267
    }
]
```